# Remove border/style from previously clicked link - React/Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a function that triggers onClick which adds borders to the clicked element.

Here is the code in the component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Link from 'next/link';
import Logo from '../../components/logo.svg';
import React from 'react';
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const {
    publicRuntimeConfig: { domain },
} = getConfig();

export default function MediaNav() {
    // If router equals link in list, show blue border
    const router = useRouter();
    const menu = ['Home', 'FAQs', 'Contact Us', 'Social Media'];
    const [selectedPage, setPage] = useState({
        borderColor: '',
    });

    const handleLinkClick = e => {
        setPage({
            borderStyle: '3px solid #005ba9',
        });
        e.target.style.borderLeft = selectedPage.borderStyle;
        e.target.style.borderRight = selectedPage.borderStyle;
    };

    return (
        <nav>
            <div>
                <Link href={`${domain}`}>
                    <a>
                        <Logo />
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <ul
            >
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li
                        >
                            <a href="/subdomain/link">All Sites</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                        <ul
                        >
                            {menu.map((item, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <li key={i}>
                                        <Link href={item === 'Home' ? '/subdomain/link' : `/subdomain/${item}`.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase()}>
                                            <a onClick={handleLinkClick}>
                                                {item}
                                            </a>
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                );
                            })}
                        </ul>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

At the moment, when the element in the link list is clicked, the blue border is being applied, however, if I click another link, I wanted the previously clicked element link to be removed its borders.

As this is NextJs and I have a `Link` tag wrapping up the link element, loading is not occurring, therefore I don't know how to make a difference between previously clicked element and currently clicked element.

Any idea how to remove the borders to already clicked link when next link is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better approach to this problem would be having a state to save `currentPage` user visiting and depending on `currentPage` state giving a style to `a` element.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import Link from 'next/link';
import Logo from '../../components/logo.svg';
import React from 'react';
import getConfig from 'next/config';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const {
    publicRuntimeConfig: { domain },
} = getConfig();

export default function MediaNav() {
    // If router equals link in list, show blue border
    const router = useRouter();
    const menu = ['Home', 'FAQs', 'Contact Us', 'Social Media'];
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState('')

    const handleLinkClick = pageName => {
        setCurrentPage(pageName);
    };

    return (
        <nav>
            <div>
                <Link href={`${domain}`}>
                    <a>
                        <Logo />
                    </a>
                </Link>
            </div>
            <ul
            >
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li
                        >
                            <a href="/subdomain/link">All Sites</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                        <ul>
                            {menu.map((item, i) => {
                                return (
                                    <li key={i}>
                                        <Link href={item === 'Home' ? '/subdomain/link' : `/subdomain/${item}`.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase()}>
                                            <a onClick={() => handleLinkClick(item)} style={{ border: currentPage === item ? '3px solid #005ba9': 'initial' }}>
                                                {item}
                                            </a>
                                        </Link>
                                    </li>
                                );
                            })}
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of adding a style on a target element, you can try adding a class, let's say `highlight` on the element.

highlight class would look like -

```
.highlight {
     border-left: '3px solid #005ba9',
     border-right: '3px solid #005ba9'
}
```

So only the elements which have this class would show the border styles applied. Since the components would re-render on state changes, make sure you are applying the `highlight` class on the link in `map` function logic. This would ensure other elements won't have this class and this would solve the problem.

PS: Removing of the previously applied styles would be tedious. I think the above solution would work without much hassle and it would work great.